# c# json with a changing class

Tags: c#, json, class, dynamic

```
public class 2500113075262000    {
    public string pair { get; set; } 
    public string type { get; set; } 
    public double amount { get; set; } 
    public int rate { get; set; } 
    public string timestamp_created { get; set; } 
    public int status { get; set; } 
}

public class Return    {
    public 2500113075262000 2500113075262000 { get; set; } 
}

public class Root    {
    public int success { get; set; } 
    public Return @return { get; set; } 
}
```

class 2500113075262000 is constantly changing, this is the order ID, like deserialize

```
{"success":1,"return":{"2500113075262000":{"pair":"eth_rur","type":"sell","amount":0.00110569,"rate":46100,"timestamp_created":"1608918997","status":0}}}
```

Comment: It would really help if you'd show the JSON you're trying to deserialize. I suspect that you actually want a `Dictionary<string, Order>` or something similar, but it's hard to tell just from what you've shown us.

Comment: {"success":1,"return":{"2500113075262000":{"pair":"eth_rur","type":"sell","amount":0.00110569,"rate":46100,"timestamp_created":"1608918997","status":0}}}

Comment: Please edit your question to show the JSON, rather than putting it as a comment.

Comment: a constantly changing class - i'd strongly recommend changing your code so your class stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's only the key - presumably the order ID - which is changing. I would suggest removing your `Return` class entirely, and changing your `Root` class to have a `Dictionary<string, Order>`. I'd also suggest writing your classes with idiomatic .NET property names, and using `JsonPropertyAttribute` to specify the representation in the JSON. So it would be something like this:

```cs
public class Order
{
    [JsonProperty("pair")]
    public string Pair { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    // etc, other properties
}

public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public int Success { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("return")]
    public Dictionary<string, Order> Returns { get; set; }
}
```